# Making an input icon (search icon) responsive

Tags: html, css

Typical for a search bar, I've added a magnifying glass icon on the left side for UI purposes. On desktop it looks fine and stays at the position nicely. However, when switching to mobile the icon is repositioning itself according to the device width.

I thought by increasing the `left` parameter for `@media (max-width: 768px)` it will be fixed but it seems to behave differently.

A gif of the issue with the code on the right side is added. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Search icon behaving differently for mobile sizes]

Comment: left:4em; , your code does what's written. ;)

Comment: share your code here not gif so we can help you in a right way.

Comment: @KuldipKoradia The css is too long as a comment.

Comment: @G-Cyr How for devices wider than 768px I have left: 0.67em but it is not behaving that way

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or codepen of your code? @MarcKöhler

Comment: @MeghnaBhuptani https://codepen.io/MarcSendcloud/pen/YzPGzZm Thanks for looking into it. 
The html is just a handlebar because the whole thing is in a Zendesk Guide theme

Comment: please update your code. There is no html in your shared link. @MarcKöhler

Comment: If you get the answer can you please accept it so others can get help from it. @MarcKöhler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.input_with_icon {
    position: relative;
}
.input_with_icon .form-control {
    padding-left: 40px;
    height: 21px;
}
.input_with_icon img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="input_with_icon">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here...">
    <img src="images/search.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because you have hard-coded left:4em inside the media query.